# Ipython deactivate terminal button on the beginning

Tags: ipython

Is there any way to start ipython notebook (running in ubuntu), but the Terminal option (from the New button) will not be activated? I don't want this in all my ipython notebooks but I'm looking for an ad-hoc way to pass some options when I start a new notebook.

Comment: It's not currently configurable, but if it fails to import `terminado`, terminals will not be available. I'm not quite sure why you want this, though - if you want to use terminals some of the time, what's the advantage in disabling the menu item?

Comment: for security reasons...

Comment: Anything you can do from a terminal you can also do from a notebook, so it doesn't really make it any more secure.